# A shared pointer which is conceptually owned by one, unique, object

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, ownership

What is the canonical way to deal with shared pointers in C++ when there is a clear case to argue that "one, unique object owns the pointer"?

For example, if a `shared_ptr` is a member of a particular class, which is responsible for initializing the pointer, then it could be argued that this class should also have the final say on when the pointer is deleted.

In other words, it may be the case that when the owning class goes out of scope (or is itself `delete`'d that any remaining references to the pointer no longer make sense. This may be due to related variables which were members of the destroyed class.

Here is a sketch of an example

```
class Owner
{

    Owner()
    {
        p.reset(malloc_object(arguments), free_object);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<type> get() { return p; } 
        // seems strange because now something somewhere
        // else in the code can hold up the deletion of p

    // unless a manual destructor is written
    ~Owner()
    {
        p.reset(nullptr); // arduous
    }

    std::shared_ptr<type> p;
    int a, b, c; // some member variables which are logically attached to p
                 // such that neither a, b, c or p make sense without each other
}
```

One cannot use a `unique_ptr` as this would not permit the pointer to be returned by the get function, unless a raw pointer is returned. (Is this is an acceptable solution?)

A `unique_ptr` in combination with returning `weak_ptr` from the get function might make sense. But this is not valid C++. `weak_ptr` is used in conjunction with `shared_ptr`.

A `shared_ptr` with the get function returning `weak_ptr` is better than a raw pointer becuase in order to use the weak pointer, it has to be converted to a shared pointer. This will fail if the reference count is already zero and the object has been deleted.

However using a `shared_ptr` defeats the point, since ideally a `unique_ptr` would be chosen because there can then only be one thing which "owns" the pointed to data.

I hope the question is clear enough, it was quite difficult to explain since I can't copy the code I am working with.

Comment: Seems to me like the obvious question would be why you're passing out a pointer to the object's internal state. That's generally discouraged for pretty much the reasons you've outlined.

Comment: If `Owner` owns the `type` object that `p` is pointing at, then `p` should not be a `shared_ptr` to begin with. But if you really needed to, then perhaps `shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor might be useful here, if you store the `Owner` object in a `shared_ptr` and then have `p` point to `type` but rely on `Owner`'s shared ownership instead.

Comment: Isn’t this exactly why `weak_ptr` exists? Could you maybe clarify the downside of `weak_ptr` in your use case.

Comment: The problem with a shared_ptr is that is is, effectively, a global — federated across all the owners.  Using a unique_ptr and handing out non-owning raw pointers has the problem of the raw pointers becoming dangling pointers.  It's a tradeoff, and both approaches have pros/cons and require a level of discipline.  (Either way the exposed object can be mutated unless only const object is exposed.)

Comment: The only reason I can think of for using `shared_ptr` here is if you want to go with passing `weak_ptr`s around so you have a measure of defense against dangling.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there's an attempt to access the object after its owner is destroyed? Are you just going to ensure that never happens? Or do you need it to fail in some sane, detectable way?

Comment: If others need to know when ressource is deleted, then `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` would be the way to go. If you need to be sure that object is not destroyed too early, then `shared_ptr` might be the right choice. Otherwise, a `unique_ptr` and returning raw pointer. In GSL (https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guideline-the-guidelines-support-library), raw pointer are considered as non owning.

Comment: Reading through these comments and reviewing again it does seem like the most sensible approach would be to use a `unique_ptr` and return a `weak_ptr`. But this isn't valid C++ code, as far as I am aware, and I don't know of a sensible way to make it valid.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It should probably be detectable.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Then you want to use `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. I'm puzzled why you think `unique_ptr`/`weak_ptr` would be sensible. How could you ever use the `weak_ptr` if there was no guarantee the object would stay around while you used it? What good is a weak pointer if you cannot convert it into an owning pointer? What good is a unique pointer if some other code has an owning pointer? Such a scheme makes no sense. The purpose of `weak_ptr` is to create another owning pointer which would be impossible if there already existed a unique pointer.

Answer (score 3):

It is ok to return the `shared_ptr` there, what will happen is that the pointer will still be held somewhere outside the `Owner` class. Since your doing `p.reset(nullptr);` at the destructor, whoever was holding that `shared_ptr` will now be holding a pointer to null.

Using `weak_ptr` with `shared_ptr` is also a good solution, the problem is the same which is the fact that the best class to represent `p` is `unique_ptr` as you described.

The path I would choose is to hold a `unique_ptr` which seems more adequate and to implement the `get()` function like this:

`type* get() { return p.get(); }`

The behaviour is the same and the code is clearer since having `p` as `unique_ptr` will give clarity on how it should be used.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I misunderstood... So if any "shared pointer" calls the function `reset()` that invalidated all the other shared pointers which reference the same resource?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant That is definitely not the case. The point of a `shared_ptr` is that all others that have a copy of the original `shared_ptr` will still reference the original object. They do *not* see the null pointer.

Comment: In that case, this seems to be the reverse of what I was expecting. I presume calling reset does at least reduce the reference count by 1?